# WordPress "wp_register_style was called incorrectly"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've google'd all over the place for an answer, but can't find any decent answers with an actual solution. So, I'll firstly explain my issue.

I'm using a custom theme that I've made, in the latest version of WordPress.

I wanted to do the proper thing, and not hardcode my styles and scripts into the header.php file, but enqueue them using WordPress functions.

**Here are the notices shown when debugging is enabled:**

```
Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project-new\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3560
```

**Here's the relevant part in my `functions.php` file:**

```
/**
 * Register global styles & scripts.
 */
wp_register_style('my-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900');
wp_register_style('fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_register_style('my-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css');

wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ));


/**
 * Enqueue global styles & scripts.
 */

wp_enqueue_style('my-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('my-fonts');
wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome');

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
```

I'm guessing from the debugging notices that I need to somehow specify to load WordPress's '`wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, I found out what I'd done wrong! Here's what I did for anyone interested:

**I changed this:**

```
/**
 * Register global styles & scripts.
 */
wp_register_style('my-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900');
wp_register_style('fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_register_style('my-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css');

wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ));


/**
 * Enqueue global styles & scripts.
 */

wp_enqueue_style('my-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('my-fonts');
wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome');

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
```

**To this:**

```
function my_scripts() {
/**
 * Register global styles & scripts.
 */
wp_register_style('my-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900');
wp_register_style('fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_register_style('my-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css');

wp_register_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ));


/**
 * Enqueue global styles & scripts.
 */

wp_enqueue_style('my-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('my-fonts');
wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome');

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
```

**And added this:**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: Note the difference between code sample A and code sample B is the addition of a function, `function y_scripts()` on line 1.

Comment: If you want to enqueue the stlyes for admin page, use `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts, 'scripts' );`

Answer (score -3):

Fixed for me deactivating "WC Fields Factory" plugin.